# Is it possible to replace char driver of already existing char device?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to write char driver for a mouse (or any other char device like keyboard). Is it possible to replace already existing char driver? If so, is it enough to implement basic file operations like open/read/write/close?

Comment: Unix device drivers generally have five entries, the four you mention plus ioctl

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course yes, but you need to try to write a simple driver first.
Please refer this file to see the USB mouse driver on the Kernel.
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbmouse.c

Answer (score 0):

Adding something...

Not only you can replace an existing driver, you can also **add** your own driver to the system, without touching the other ones. You create a node (see mknod) in the file system, where you want, and assign it major and minor device number of your driver. At that point, you can even tell some program to use the normal stock driver, and some other program to use your own, special driver.

Hope this can help.